# Recompensar respostas de qualidade

Tags: debate, recompensa, qualidade

Venho aqui propor algo que venho fazendo há algum tempo e aparentemente o [Wallace Maxters](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/4995/wallace-maxters) também. E há [estatísticas gerais](https://data.stackexchange.com/pt/query/899078/top-investors) onde vemos que o [gustavox](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/23400/gustavox) fazia muito isso, o [Guilherme Nascimento](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/3635/guilherme-nascimento) dá bastante recompensa (não sei se por causa disto).

Estou destacando algumas perguntas que acho que merecem uma resposta canônica, ou de qualidade. Em geral, já tem uma resposta muito boa, mas pode parecer uma nova melhor. Colocando uma recompensa a pergunta, e por consequência as respostas, ficam por até uma semana em destaque na aba específica e dá uma oportunidade a mais para as pessoas que não viram terem contato com alguma resposta interessante que pode ajudá-las a se tornarem desenvolvedores melhores.

O objetivo é **dar visibilidade a informações que nem todos sabem e que podem ser úteis**.

O critério do que escolher é de cada um e o motivo escolhido também. O quanto colocar de recompensa também. Mas acho legal deixar os 7 dias (só tomando cuidado para não esquecer de mandar a recompensa para alguma resposta no final do período). Claro, seria bom realmente destacar coisas interessantes.

Eu tenho feito 3 por semana que é o limite. Estou dando de volta pra comunidade um pouco da reputação que ganhei, e eu gosto da reputação. Eu espero que as pessoas que dizem que não estão fazendo nada por pontos possam participar de forma até mais ativa que eu, assim não fica só no discurso.

Ninguém é obrigado fazê-lo, mas seria legal termos bastantes adesões.

Se tiver dúvidas tem uma [FAQ sobre *bounties*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/bounty).

## Vamos participar?

[Recompensas ajudam](https://data.stackexchange.com/pt/query/196596/bounty-stats-what-can-a-bounty-do-for-you). Poucos vão no meio termo, [ou dá pouco, ou vai com tudo no máximo](https://data.stackexchange.com/pt/query/8164/amount-of-bounties-for-each-bounty-amount). E como curiosidade [os que mais ganham recompensas](https://data.stackexchange.com/pt/query/899077/top-100-bounty-earners).

Comment: +1 Muito boa a iniciativa. Apesar de eu falar várias vezes em tom de zoação, acho que a ideia é totalmente válida e é um mecanismo que está a nossa disposição para fazer com que os usuários novos tenha acesso aos conteúdos mais antigos e bons que existem no site.

Answer (score 19):

Acredito não ser uma resposta propriamente dita, mas gostaria de contribuir com a minha experiencia em oferecer a primeira recompensa.

Sou novo no site, não tem um ano que faço parte, mas já reparei que temos espalhadas pelo site várias perguntas e respostas na maioria dos casos que estão "datadas", ou seja, algumas respostas de 2014/15/... não fazem mais sentido hoje em dia, ou então estão obsoletas, ou não é mais uma boa prática, etc...

Ao oferecer uma recompensa reparei nesse quadro perguntando o motivo da recompensa que achei bem interessante e gostaria de compartilhar.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

As opções realmente fazem jus a ofertar uma recompensa. E fazem mais sentido ainda quanto pensamos na manutenção e longevidade da "comunidade", visto que devemos prezar por manter a qualidade e valor do nosso conteúdo.

*Fica ai meu depoimento, espero que mais pessoas se disponham a participar. E reforçar ainda mais o StackOverflow como um lugar com conteúdo de qualidade e uma fonte de referência válida e atual*

Comment: Este é um excelente motivo para recompensar!

Comment: Ainda aprendi uma palavra nova hoje, «ofertar», que eu não conhecia.

Comment: @JorgeB. Ofertar: https://www.dicio.com.br/ofertar/ infelizmente uma palavra rara de se ver hj em dia :/

Comment: @hugocsl sim eu sei, eu fui ver o que é.