# Como lidar com uma pergunta útil, mas temporal?

Tags: suporte, pergunta-específica

Encontrei uma pergunta hoje que é algo que *quase* qualquer um que vá mexer com React Native se questiona: [Quais as reais diferenças em criar um projeto com Expo e sem Expo?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/298637/100416).

É uma pergunta muito útil, existem diferentes pontos a serem abordados que vão desde as diferenças até um - levemente subjetivo - "vale ou não a pena?" (*spoiler: depende*). O ponto é que uma resposta de 2018 é com certeza bem diferente de uma resposta hoje, que provavelmente será bem diferente de uma em 2022.

Para quem não conhece, o Expo é "tipo" um *wrapper* pro desenvolvimento de um aplicativo com React Native, e evoluiu bastante nesse meio tempo, por isso a resposta seria bem diferente - apesar do cerne ser o mesmo.

Em um caso desses, o que deve ser feito?

- A pergunta deveria ter sido fechada em 2018? - [Houve votação](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/review/close/167498)
- Deveria ser fechada hoje?
- Seria legal alguém responder algo mais atualizado?
- Nenhuma das opções anteriores?

---

PS: Não tenho certeza se a pergunta que mencionei está dentro do escopo do SOpt ou se tem algum outro problema nela.

Comment: Seria legal a pergunta ser respondida com clareza de que é temporal para que quem lesse tivesse noção de que ela pode estar desatualizada ou depender da versão que você usa do recurso esclarecido. Também seria legal alguém responder algo mais atualizado. Eu acho que a abordagem correta é abrir uma nova pergunta pela nova solução do velho problema no novo contexto.

Comment: @RHERWOLF obrigado por comentar, mas não acho que abrir uma nova pergunta seja uma boa opção. Me parece que [oferecer uma recompensa "As respostas atuais estão desatualizadas"](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/7316/100416) seria melhor nesse caso

Comment: Acho que isso é um problema bem mais geral do que se parece. Praticamente toda tecnologia atual está em constante evolução (caso contrário para no tempo e eventualmente ficará obsoleta). Portanto, de certo modo, toda pergunta é um pouco "temporal". Na _minha_ opinião, não é algo errado e que deve ser evitado. No entanto, acho que o autor da resposta deve procurar atualizá-la com o tempo, se necessário. Por exemplo, às vezes vejo o Maniero editando algumas perguntas sobre .NET (principalmente quando é relacionada à versão ou algo do tipo).

Comment: Em suma, acho que cada autor tinha que prezar pela manutenção e "atualidade" da própria resposta. Mas esse nem sempre será o caso, o que decerto gera certos ruídos para o site em formato de respostas desatualizadas. Aí alguém poderia criar outra resposta, se o autor da original não tiver atualizado, mas também corre o risco do autor da pergunta não atualizar a aceitação. Enfim, realmente não tem um caminho definido para esse tipo de situação. Cabe debate mesmo.

Comment: @LuizFelipe bom ponto. Comentei do Expo porque de fato dois anos atrás você podia dizer "não recomendo usar", enquanto hoje a situação mudou bastante - diferentemente de uma específicação de uma linguagem, por exemplo, mas concordo com o que você diz. A aceitação pode ser um problema, mas se for uma pergunta que chame a atenção da comunidade, votos e eventuais recompensas acabarão "organizando" a situação.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Existem muitos aonde surgem novas respostas, geralmente citando algo semelhante:

> a partir da versão X.Y.Z lançada em xx/yy/zzzz o recurso se tornou obsoleto e agora devemos usar este meio

Até mesmo em api bem básicas, quando ocorre alguma mudança. Tanto que é por isso que existe a recompensa para atrair novas respostas

> [image: recompensa para buscar respostas atualizadas]

> nota: lancei uma recompensa como incentivo nessa pergunta, mas quem notar que uma pergunta precisa de uma resposta atualizada, também pode oferecer e ajudar a comunidade com conteúdo atualizado.

Comment: Acho que esse realmente é o caminho, só encontrei a [resposta que mencionei sobre essa recompensa](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/7316/100416) depois de ter aberto a pergunta. O mais importante aqui é que agora sei que perguntas assim são válidas. Obrigado pela resposta (e pela recompensa na pergunta) :).